# Addresses are off by two bytes

Tags: assembly, x86, macros, nasm, bootloader

Whenever I assemble my scripts with `nasm boot.asm -o boot.bin`, everything works fine except for the locations of strings being off by a few bytes.

Here's what my `boot.asm` looks like:

```
[org 0x7C00]
[bits 16]

%include "stack.mac"
%include "string.mac"
%include "prepareenv.mac"

SECTION .text
GLOBAL _entry

_entry:
  prepareenv _entry

  PUSH message
  PUSH strlen(message)
  CALL _putchars

  JMP $

string message, db "Running."

%include "putchars.asm"

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

Here's essentially what my `putchars.asm` looks like (pushm and rpopm are macros that expand to individual pushes and pops for each argument. They live in `stack.mac`):

```
%ifndef _PUTCHARS_
%define _PUTCHARS_

%include "stack.mac"

; Arg 0: word(2) String address
; Arg 1: word(2) String length
_putchars:
  PUSH EBP
  MOV EBP, ESP
  pushm AX, BX, CX, SI

  MOV SI, [EBP + 4] ; Load string address
  MOV CX, [EBP + 6] ; Load string length

  MOV AH, 0x0E ; Print function
  XOR BX, BX   ; Zero BX

  _putchars_print_loop:
    MOV AL, [SI + BX]         ; Move current character into string
    CMP BX, CX                ; Have we reached the full string length?
    JE  _putchars_ret         ; If so, we can terminate
    INT 0x10                  ; Interrupt to BIOS
    INC BX                    ; Increment BX
    JMP _putchars_print_loop  ; Repeat string loop

  putchars_ret:
    rpopm AX, BX, CX, SI
    POP EBP
    RET 4

%endif
```

Here's what my `string.mac` looks like:

```
%ifndef _STRING_
%define _STRING_

%macro string 2+
  %{1}: %{2}
  %{1}_length equ ($ - %{1})
%endmacro

%define strlen(name) name%+_length

%endif
```

`prepareenv.mac` simply clears out all the segment registers. Removing it doesn't change anything, so it's unimportant.

When `boot.asm` hits `PUSH message`, the address loaded is 2 bytes before the string actually starts in memory. This occurs no matter the string and happens in any other file I include (I have other scripts, but I've stripped it down to what I've posted here and it behaves the same way)

I'm suspecting a bug in NASM, but a workaround (if possible) would be nice.

Comment: You are mixing 16 and 32-bit memory operands, and you have the order of the arguments wrong in `_putchars`. You push the address first and the length second. Those pushes push 2 bytes each. The problem is that for some reason you are using EBP (and not BP). When you push EBP on the stack that is 4 bytes. Then there are 2 bytes for the return address (from the call). Your first parameter is at EBP+6 and second parameter is EBP+8. You then reverse those and it should be `MOV SI, [EBP + 8]` and `MOV CX, [EBP + 6]`

Comment: I recommend if you are writing 16-bit code for a bootloader you stick to the 16-bit registers. Use BP instead of EBP and SP instead of ESP.  Making that change you'd also have to change `_putchars` code to be `MOV SI, [BP + 6]` and `MOV CX, [BP + 4]` since BP being pushed on the stack is 2 bytes, return address is 2 bytes. First parameter (length) is at BP+4 and the address of the string is at BP+6.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Many thanks! `MOV CX, [EBP + 6]` still with 4-byte address explains why the length was still working even though I was sure the stack was behaving oddly. I had thought about about the order of those args, but since it was off by two bytes, I figured it was right. Crazy how it wasn't complete garbage.

The reason I was using EBP is because I figured NASM would cut it down to BP after assembly once it saw the `bits 16` directive, but that was a foolish assumption (though, I don't even understand why I chose to use EBP at this point)

Comment: No problem. NASM can't change EBP to BP because in 16-bit code - memory operands are actually allowed to use 32-bit addressing. Of course that kind of code only works if run on a 386 and will cause problems on anything that isn't at least a 386 processor.